# How to loop through an array that triggers an click event on each item in the array one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having trouble with something in my function. I am trying to trigger click events one after another with a short delay between each item of my array...if anybody can explain to me how to fix It and why. I will be very grateful for any help.

```js
var track3 = new Audio();
track3.src= 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3';

head= $("#head").click (function (){
  $("#head").css ("background-color","black");
  $("#head").css({ opacity: 0.9});
  track3.play ();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#head").css({ opacity: 0.0 });
    $("#head").css("background-color","");
  }, 300);
});

shoulders= $("#shoulders").click (function (){
  $("#shoulders").css ("background-color","cyan");
  track3.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#shoulders").css("background-color","");
  }, 300);
});

knees= $("#knees").click (function (){
  $("#knees").css ("background-color","mediumPurple");
  track3.play ();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#knees").css("background-color", "");
  }, 300);
});

toes= $("#toes").click (function (){
  $("#toes").css ("background-color","mediumSpringGreen");
  track3.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#toes").css("background-color", "");
  }, 300);
})

var round= 0;
var player= [ ];
var simon=[ ];
var pat= ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "toes"];

$(".start").click(function (){
  simon=[ ];
  player=[ ];
  round=0;
  additionalRound();
})

function additionalRound(){
  round ++;
  $("h2").html("Round:" +round);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("h2").html("HEAD, SHOULDERS, KNEES, AND TOES!");
  },2660);
  sequence();
}

function sequence (){
  simon.push(pat[Math.floor (Math.random ()*4 )]);
  blinkerBeats ();
}

function blinkerBeats() {
  for (var i = 0; i < simon.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(simon[i]).trigger('click');
    }, i * 800);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `if (i >= simon.length)` doesn't make sense. That means that inside the if block when you say `simon[i]` you get `undefined` because you've gone past the end of the array..

Comment: thank you for helping me understand my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I edited your question into readable code. Here's what are looking for:

```js
function sequence (){
  simon.push(pat[Math.floor (Math.random ()*4 )]);
  blinkerBeats (simon);
}

function blinkerBeats(arr) {
  var timer = 0,
      interval = 800;
  arr.map(function(elem){
    timer++;
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#'+elem).trigger('click');
    }, timer * interval)
  })
}
```

Right now, `simon.push()` in your `sequence()` function only adds 1 entry to the array. If you actually want a sequence, you probably want to do:

```
function sequence (times){
  for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    simon.push(pat[Math.floor (Math.random ()*4 )]);
  }
  blinkerBeats (simon);
}
```

**Working example:** Since I don't have your initial markup, I just used some simple `<input>`s to test the code. Please note I didn't change the rest of your functions (as I'm not familiar to their logic - I only changes `sequence()` and `blinkerBeats()` functions:

```js
var track3 = new Audio();
track3.src= 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3';

head= $("#head").click (function (){
  $("#head").css ("background-color","black");
  $("#head").css({ opacity: 0.9});
  track3.play ();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#head").css({ opacity: 0.0 });
    $("#head").css("background-color","");
  }, 300);
});

shoulders= $("#shoulders").click (function (){
  $("#shoulders").css ("background-color","cyan");
  track3.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#shoulders").css("background-color","");
  }, 300);
});

knees= $("#knees").click (function (){
  $("#knees").css ("background-color","mediumPurple");
  track3.play ();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#knees").css("background-color", "");
  }, 300);
});

toes= $("#toes").click (function (){
  $("#toes").css ("background-color","mediumSpringGreen");
  track3.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#toes").css("background-color", "");
  }, 300);
})

var round= 0;
var player= [ ];
var simon=[ ];
var pat= ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "toes"];

$(".start").click(function (){
  simon=[ ];
  player=[ ];
  round=0;
  additionalRound();
})

function additionalRound(){
  round ++;
  $("h2").html("Round:" +round);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("h2").html("HEAD, SHOULDERS, KNEES, AND TOES!");
  },2660);
  sequence($('#clicks').val());
}

function sequence (times){
  for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    simon.push(pat[Math.floor (Math.random ()*4 )]);
  }
  blinkerBeats (simon);
}

function blinkerBeats(arr) {
  var timer = 0,
      interval = 800;
  arr.map(function(elem){
    timer++;
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#'+elem).trigger('click');
    }, timer * interval)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="head"> Head</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="shoulders">Shoulders</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="knees">Knees</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="toes">Toes</label>
<hr />
Times: <input type="number" value="6" id="clicks" />
<input type="button" value="Start" class="start" />


<h2>Click start!</h2>
```

Comment: @Reb I realized the initial code wasn't good and I couldn't properly test it because you haven't made a [mcve]. I updated my answer with a new approach and you can see it working. Let me know if you have trouble applying it to your use case. If you do, you'll have to share more of your code, so I could test. Up so far you only showed dead code.

Comment: I am going to edit my question and add all my JavaScript and jQuery code...I am sorry for the lack of information provided in my question. I am new. You are very helpful, and patent.

Comment: If you reproduce your problem here or in jsFiddle, I can help you figure out why. But, as you can see, here it works. I can't debug something I'm not able to inspect.

Comment: Your fiddle contained the initial code I provided. Additionally, your `pat` contained `$` before names, resulting in `$(`$head`).click()` calls being made. [`Fixed it`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/pudtxtvo/). Also streamlined three identical functions in only one. Take care.